# PWA Android fullscreen display : <body> doesn't take 100% of the <html> wrapper

Tags: scroll, progressive-web-apps

I created a PWA with a display "fullscreen" specified in the manifest. However, the body doesn't take 100% of the height of its HTML parent. The body is scrollable and doesn't take the whole height

Here the basic CSS

```css
html,
body,
#root {
  background: green;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

The HTML opened by the PWA

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html translate="no" class="notranslate" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; viewport-fit=cover" />
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
    <meta name="description" content="Flink HubOne App" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="180x180" />
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/mask-icon.png" color="#FFFFFF" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="background-color: red; flex: 1; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
      <h1>TEST</h1>
      <h1>TEST</h1>
      <h1>TEST</h1>
      <h1>TEST</h1>
      <h1>TEST</h1>
      <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here the configuration used for my PWA

```json
manifest: {
    id: "/",
    name: "Test App",
    short_name: "Test",
    description: "Test",
    theme_color: "#ffffff",
    display: "fullscreen",
    scope: "/",
    start_url: "/",
  },
```

[image: screenshot of the result]

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with the following workaround:

1. In the PWA manifest, replace `fullscreen` with `standalone`:

```json
display: "standalone"
```

2. In the HTML page, define a `meta` tag to allow full screen:

```html
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

3. In the Javascript code, call [requestFullscreen()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen):

```js
document.body.requestFullscreen()
```

Comment: Actually #2 is not necessary.